# What is the name of the command that shows disk access in real time?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, io

I am running Mac OS X ( 10.9.4 ) using the built in Terminal, and bash version:
3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)

At one point in the past, there was a CLI command I could issue that would show me what was going on with my drives, kind of like a tail -f system.log but deeper into the system where it would look at the actual drives and what was going on.  A fully idle machine, say one that was sleeping and I was ssh'd into, would show a page that was doing little or nothing.  Saving a file, or doing anything disk related, and tons of data would scroll past, which you could pipe to a file and grep through.

I have goggled and can't find this command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/97980/view-filesystem-access-in-real-time-on-mac-os-x

Comment: Indeed, a duplicate, those are the command I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: I use fs_usage.  Handy tool to trace all file system calls (file system usage). I also wrote about it on my blog along with an example in case you are interested.  http://mohit.io/blog/fs_usage-trace-file-system-calls-on-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Mac OS X, but on Linux, there are several:

```
iostat
iotop
sar
dstat
vmstat
iozone
```

Most of them should be available on Mac OS X. I know that iostat is.
Or you can always look in

```
/sys/block/[device]/stat
```

or

```
/proc/diskstats
```

Answer (score 0):

This was in fact a duplicate of question noted by anishane.

The command I was looking for was  `fs_usage` but `lsof`, while not exactly what I wanted, is a close second in being helpful to track down the problems I'm running into.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for iosnoop. Seems like it is a wrapper on dstat only, as when I ran it without sudo it gave me the following error.

```
    % iosnoop
dtrace: system integrity protection is on, some features will not be available
dtrace: failed to initialize dtrace: DTrace requires additional privileges
```

Comment: Or it could have been the one he said it was four years ago ¯\_(ツ)_/¯